# client socket is bindable but not connectable, because already in use

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock

I write a client, where i have to bind the client socket. This works fine. After that i try to connect the Socket and i get error 10048. (Address already in use.) I don't understand how this is possible.

I have to implement a client speaking with multiple server. Every server only accepts messages from a specific port. (every Server expects a different port). so i have to bind my client socket. The code above is to create one of these sockets.
My code works some times. But very often the connect gives me the error 10048, while the binding before was fine. I know that bind can give also the error 10048 if the socket is already in use. But it doesn't. It returns 0. So i guess the port is free. Immediate after binding i call connect and get error 10048. I do not understand why? At the moment of the binding the port was obviously free.

```
bool TEthernetSocket::Open()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;

    if (WSAStartup((MAKEWORD(2, 0)), &wsaData) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
       return IsConnected();
    }

    Socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // TCP

    if (Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //bind Socket
    struct sockaddr_in sa_loc;
    memset(&sa_loc, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    sa_loc.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa_loc.sin_port = htons(ClientPort);
    sa_loc.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IPClient.substr(0, 15).c_str());

    CALL_TRACE_CB("ethernetSocket connected");

    if (!(bind(Socket, (struct sockaddr*)&sa_loc, sizeof(struct  
    sockaddr))))
    {
        CALL_TRACE_CB("Bind works");
    }
    else
    {
        AnsiString msg = AnsiString().sprintf("EN: error socket Bind: 
        %d", WSAGetLastError());
        CALL_ERROR_CB(ERROR_NO_PORT_HANDLE, msg.c_str());
        Close();
    }


    // TCP
    SOCKADDR_IN sAdd;
    sAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sAdd.sin_port = htons(Port);
    sAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP.substr(0, 15).c_str());

    if (connect(Socket, (SOCKADDR*)&sAdd, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN)) ==    
    SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        AnsiString msg = AnsiString().sprintf("EN: error connect        
        errorcode: %d", WSAGetLastError());
    }
}
```

I expect that bind() returns 10048 before connect returns this error, but actual only connect() returns this error

Comment: 'Every server only accepts messages from a specific port': why?

Answer (score 1):

> I have to implement a client speaking with multiple server. The server only accepts messages from a specific port, so i have to bind my client socket.

This is an unsolvable problem. When you make an outbound TCP connection, the combination of local IP address and port is reserved exclusively for that particular outbound TCP connection. If you need to make multiple outbound TCP connections from the same port, each will have to be bound to its own local IP address. That is going to be extremely inconvenient.

There are other problems too. Say you finish one connection and then try to start a new one. The new one will have the same local IP address, local port (since the server only tolerates one), remote IP address, and remote port. How will packets  from the new connection be distinguished from old, stale packets from the old one?

This is why you get the error when you try to `connect`. It's not until all four parameters of the connection (local and remote address and local and remote port) are known that the collision with the prior connection is detectable. That's not known until you call `connect`.

You need to fix the server to ignore the source port. If that absolutely cannot be done, you'll have to adopt a wait and retry mechanism to handle collisions with past connections.

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't clear. Every server, i communicate with, expects an other specific port. Thank you. I edit this

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It's not *necessarily* a problem that needs to be fixed. Clients can bind if they want to ensure they're connecting from a specific IP and/or source port. Most programs only care about the destination IP and port, but sometimes the source matters. Binding to a particular source port does mean there can only be one connection at a time per IP.

Comment: @JimmyDiJim Then this is going to happen all the time as new connections collide with older ones. You can wait and retry. But really, you should fix the server to ignore the source port. (See updates.)

Comment: That said, I agree that it's unusual and unlikely. The OP might misunderstand the requirement.

Comment: @All. It's like John Kugelman said. Clients can bind Sockets. It's unusual. But possible. In my case, the server care about the source( IP and Port).

Comment: @JimmyDiJim Then you're going to need to implement some wait and retry logic when your connections collide with each other, sorry. Try to get the server fixed. It's an unreasonable requirement.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: I have no access to the server. Seems like i need to call with the company.But i don't understand the problem. I need only one connection per server with one specific socket. p.e. server 1 needs port 2000, server 2 needs port 2001 and so on. So every socket is unique. It should only collide if the socket is still open from an older connection.If the adress is already in use, why can i bind. shouldn't bind return me error 10048, when the adress is already in  use.

Comment: @JimmyDiJim Whether or not the socket is open has little to do with whether or not the previous connection is sufficiently stale to reuse all four of its core parameters. The conflict isn't on the local port. The conflict is with the prior connection. It's not the address that's still in use, it's the 4-tuple that identifies the connection that's still in use. Punch "2MSL" into your favorite search engine.